# How to get the Pixel ID of an ad account - Facebook marketing API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-pixel

Is it possible to get the Pixel ID of an ad account thru the Facebook Marketing API? and if so, how to call the API?

I took a look at the documentation but I'm unable to find out how to do it

[audiences-api/pixel/](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/audiences-api/pixel/)

[reference/ads-pixel/](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ads-pixel/)

Comment: Please post the code showing where you are getting stuck. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

As [described in the doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/audiences-api/pixel/#readpixel):

```
If a pixel exists for an ad account, get the code with Marketing API
with an HTTP GET to
https://graph.facebook.com/<API_VERSION>/act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/adspixels.
```

Otherwise you [could create it](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/audiences-api/pixel/#createpixel):

```
To create a pixel, HTTP POST to https://graph.facebook.com/<API_VERSION>/act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/adspixels.
```

Comment: I tried that and I get an error with the 'act_' object, could you try to create one and share the result?

Comment: @NestorE could you please share the error you receive? Or an example of the API Call you have tried?